# facebook scrape image shows another image than the one specified

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

when I try to share my webpage , I set the og:image to image and the facebook share button view another page .
I went to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
it displays weird things like (*og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough.*) I checked the image url as the **og:image** and it is downloadable, big enough and should be OK .
the page I am testing is http://kelmih.com/Pages/News/Details.aspx?BID=32

and my meta tags looks like

```
<meta property="og:title" content='"قراءات في المسألة الاسرائيلية" جديد الدكتور بدران '>
    
<meta property="og:description" content="وقع الكلمة - صدر
        عن دار البيروني للنشر والتوزيع كت">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://kelmih.com/Photos/News/32.jpg">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="وقع الكلمة الاخباري">
```

but the scraper shows  the image http://kelmih.com/Photos/News/82.jpg

***am I doing something wrong ?***

Comment: "use an image that's at least 200x200px". http://kelmih.com/Photos/News/32.jpg is not bigger than 200x200px

Comment: It is more than 200×200 . as I said in my question . . . I checked it and it is big enough

Comment: you are right WizKid it is 253X199 ; that is why . . . thanks